# D3 force layout works in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, d3.js, compatibility

I've created a force-layout using D3 (see image below). However, for some reason it does not work in Firefox, whereas it works perfectly fine in Chrome. There's no errors in the Firefox debugger, but it only shows me a single line in the right side of the browser (as if the force layout never updates). I'm debugging it using a local server and browsing at http://localhost:8888/.

I've been looking at different posts regarding compatibility on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to find anything related to my code. If someone could give me a header on what to debug first, that would be great!

**Edit:** I've included links to the data as well as the csv-files in plain text at the bottom of my post. Data and code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ksh2qk1b5s9lfq5/Network%20View.zip?dl=0

Here's the output from the Firefox console:

```
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create d3.js:553:4
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified d3.js:562:0
```

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.legend {                                                   
         font-size: 10px;                                         
      }                                                           
rect {                                                      
stroke-width: 2;                                          
}          

.node circle {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

line {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-opacity: 1.0;
  //stroke: "black"; 
}

body {
  /* Scaling for different browsers */
  -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  transform: scale(1,1);
}

svg{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="papaparse.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="networkview.js"></script>
</body>
```

**networkview.js**

```
var line_diff = 0.5;  // increase from zero if you want space between the call/text lines
var mark_offset = 10; // how many percent of the mark lines in each end are not used for the relationship between incoming/outgoing?
var mark_size = 5;    // size of the mark on the line

var legendRectSize = 9; // 18
var legendSpacing = 4; // 4
var recordTypes = [];
var legend;

var text_links_data, call_links_data;

// colors for the different parts of the visualization
recordTypes.push({
    text : "call",
    color : "#438DCA"
});

recordTypes.push({
    text : "text",
    color : "#70C05A"
});

recordTypes.push({
    text : "balance",
    color : "#245A76"
});

// Function for grabbing a specific property from an array
pluck = function (ary, prop) {
    return ary.map(function (x) {
        return x[prop]
    });
}

// Sums an array
sum = function (ary) {
    return ary.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b
    }, 0);
}

maxArray = function (ary) {
        return ary.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return Math.max(a, b)
        }, -Infinity);
    }

minArray = function (ary) {
    return ary.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return Math.min(a, b)
    }, Infinity);
}

var data_links;
var data_nodes;

var results = Papa.parse("links.csv", {
        header : true,
        download : true,
        dynamicTyping : true,
        delimiter : ",",
        skipEmptyLines : true,
        complete : function (results) {
            data_links = results.data;
            dataLoaded();
        }
    });

var results = Papa.parse("nodes.csv", {
        header : true,
        download : true,
        dynamicTyping : true,
        delimiter : ",",
        skipEmptyLines : true,
        complete : function (results) {
            data_nodes = results.data;
            data_nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
                d.size = (i == 0)? 200 : 30
                d.fill = (d.no_network_info == 1)? "#dfdfdf": "#a8a8a8"
            });
            dataLoaded();
        }
    });

function node_radius(d) {
    return Math.pow(40.0 * ((d.index == 0) ? 200 : 30), 1 / 3);
}
function node_radius_data(d) {
    return Math.pow(40.0 * d.size, 1 / 3);
}

function dataLoaded() {
    if (typeof data_nodes === "undefined" || typeof data_links === "undefined") {
        //console.log("Still loading")
    } else {
        CreateVisualizationFromData();
    }
}

function isConnectedToOtherThanMain(a) {
    var connected = false;
    for (i = 1; i < data_nodes.length; i++) {
        if (isConnected(a, data_nodes[i]) && a.index != i) {
            connected = true;
        }
    }
    return connected;
}

function isConnected(a, b) {
    return isConnectedAsTarget(a, b) || isConnectedAsSource(a, b) || a.index == b.index;
}

function isConnectedAsSource(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}

function isConnectedAsTarget(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
}

function isEqual(a, b) {
    return a.index == b.index;
}

function tick() {

    if (call_links_data.length > 0) {
        callLink
        .attr("x1", function (d) {
            return d.source.x - line_perpendicular_shift(d, 1)[0] + line_radius_shift_to_edge(d, 0)[0];
        })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
            return d.source.y - line_perpendicular_shift(d, 1)[1] + line_radius_shift_to_edge(d, 0)[1];
        })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
            return d.target.x - line_perpendicular_shift(d, 1)[0] + line_radius_shift_to_edge(d, 1)[0];
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
            return d.target.y - line_perpendicular_shift(d, 1)[1] + line_radius_shift_to_edge(d, 1)[1];
        });
        callLink.each(function (d) {
            applyGradient(this, "call", d)
        });
    }

    if (text_links_data.length > 0) {
        textLink
        .attr("x1", function (d) {
            return d.source.x - line_perpendicular_shift(d, -1)[0] + line_radius_shift_to_edge(d, 0)[0];
        })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
            return d.source.y - line_perpendicular_shift(d, -1)[1] + line_radius_shift_to_edge(d, 0)[1];
        })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
            return d.target.x - line_perpendicular_shift(d, -1)[0] + line_radius_shift_to_edge(d, 1)[0];
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
            return d.target.y - line_perpendicular_shift(d, -1)[1] + line_radius_shift_to_edge(d, 1)[1];
        });
        textLink.each(function (d) {
            applyGradient(this, "text", d)
        });

        node
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
    }



    if (force.alpha() < 0.05)
        drawLegend();
}

function getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (100000 - 0));
}

function applyGradient(line, interaction_type, d) {
    var self = d3.select(line);

    var current_gradient = self.style("stroke")
        current_gradient = current_gradient.substring(4, current_gradient.length - 1);

    var new_gradient_id = "line-gradient" + getRandomInt();

    var from = d.source.size < d.target.size ? d.source : d.target;
    var to = d.source.size < d.target.size ? d.target : d.source;

    var mid_offset = 0;
    var standardColor = "";

    if (interaction_type == "call") {
        mid_offset = d.inc_calls / (d.inc_calls + d.out_calls);
        standardColor = "#438DCA";
    } else {
        mid_offset = d.inc_texts / (d.inc_texts + d.out_texts);
        standardColor = "#70C05A";
    }

    /* recordTypes_ID = pluck(recordTypes, 'text');
    whichRecordType = recordTypes_ID.indexOf(interaction_type);
    standardColor = recordTypes[whichRecordType].color;
 */
    mid_offset = mid_offset * 100;
    mid_offset = mid_offset * 0.6 + 20; // scale so it doesn't hit the ends

    lineLengthCalculation = function (x, y, x0, y0) {
        return Math.sqrt((x -= x0) * x + (y -= y0) * y);
    };

    lineLength = lineLengthCalculation(from.px, from.py, to.px, to.py);

    if (lineLength >= 0.1) {
        mark_size_percent = (mark_size / lineLength) * 100;

        defs.append("linearGradient")
        .attr("id", new_gradient_id)
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("x1", from.px)
        .attr("y1", from.py)
        .attr("x2", to.px)
        .attr("y2", to.py)
        .selectAll("stop")
        .data([{
                    offset : "0%",
                    color : standardColor,
                    opacity : "1"
                }, {
                    offset : Math.round(mid_offset - mark_size_percent / 2) + "%",
                    color : standardColor,
                    opacity : "1"
                }, {
                    offset : Math.round(mid_offset - mark_size_percent / 2) + "%",
                    color : standardColor,
                    opacity : "1"
                }, {
                    offset : Math.round(mid_offset - mark_size_percent / 2) + "%",
                    color : "#245A76",
                    opacity : "1"
                }, {
                    offset : Math.round(mid_offset + mark_size_percent / 2) + "%",
                    color : "#245A76",
                    opacity : "1"
                }, {
                    offset : Math.round(mid_offset + mark_size_percent / 2) + "%",
                    color : standardColor,
                    opacity : "1"
                }, {
                    offset : Math.round(mid_offset + mark_size_percent / 2) + "%",
                    color : standardColor,
                    opacity : "1"
                }, {
                    offset : "100%",
                    color : standardColor,
                    opacity : "1"
                }
            ])
        .enter().append("stop")

        .attr("offset", function (d) {
            return d.offset;
        })
        .attr("stop-color", function (d) {
            return d.color;
        })
        .attr("stop-opacity", function (d) {
            return d.opacity;
        });

        self.style("stroke", "url(#" + new_gradient_id + ")")

        defs.select(current_gradient).remove();
    }
}

var linkedByIndex;

var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force;
var callLink;
var textLink;
var link;
var node;
var defs;
var total_interactions = 0;
var max_interactions = 0;

function CreateVisualizationFromData() {

    for (i = 0; i < data_links.length; i++) {
        total_interactions += data_links[i].inc_calls + data_links[i].out_calls + data_links[i].inc_texts + data_links[i].out_texts;
        max_interactions = Math.max(max_interactions, data_links[i].inc_calls + data_links[i].out_calls + data_links[i].inc_texts + data_links[i].out_texts)
    }

    linkedByIndex = {};

    data_links.forEach(function (d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.source + "," + d.target] = true;
        //linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = true;
    });

    //console.log(total_interactions);
    //console.log(max_interactions);

    function chargeForNode(d, i) {
        // main node
        if (i == 0) {
            return -25000;
        }
        // contains other links
        else if (isConnectedToOtherThanMain(d)) {
            return -2000;
        } else {
            return -1200;
        }
    }

    // initial placement of nodes prevents overlaps
    central_x = width / 2
    central_y = height / 2

    data_nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
    if (i != 0) {
            connected = isConnectedToOtherThanMain(d);
            data_nodes[i].x = connected? central_x + 10000: central_x -10000;
            data_nodes[i].y = connected? central_y: central_y;
    }
    else {data_nodes[i].x = central_x; data_nodes[i].y = central_y;}})

    force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(data_nodes)
        .links(data_links)
        .charge(function (d, i) {
            return chargeForNode(d, i)
        })
        .friction(0.6) // 0.6
        .gravity(0.4) // 0.6
        .size([width, height])
        .start();

    call_links_data = data_links.filter(function(d) {
        return (d.inc_calls + d.out_calls > 0)});
    text_links_data = data_links.filter(function(d) {
        return (d.inc_texts + d.out_texts > 0)});

    callLink = svg.selectAll(".call-line")
        .data(call_links_data)
        .enter().append("line");
    textLink = svg.selectAll(".text-line")
        .data(text_links_data)
        .enter().append("line");
    link = svg.selectAll("line");

    node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(data_nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node");


    defs = svg.append("defs");

    node
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", node_radius)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return (d.index == 0)? "#ffffff" : d.fill;
    })
    .style("stroke", function (d) {
        return (d.index == 0)? "#8C8C8C" : "#ffffff";
    })

    svg
    .append("marker")
    .attr("id", "arrowhead")
    .attr("refX", 6 + 7)
    .attr("refY", 2)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 4)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z");

    if (text_links_data.length > 0) {
        textLink
        .style("stroke-width", function stroke(d) {
            return text_width(d)
        })
        .each(function (d) {
            applyGradient(this, "text", d)
        });
    }

    if (call_links_data.length > 0) {
        callLink
        .style("stroke-width", function stroke(d) {
            return call_width(d)
        })
        .each(function (d) {
            applyGradient(this, "call", d)
        });
    }

    force
    .on("tick", tick);

}

function drawLegend() {

    var node_px = pluck(data_nodes, 'px');
    var node_py = pluck(data_nodes, 'py');
    var nodeLayoutRight  = Math.max(maxArray(node_px));
    var nodeLayoutBottom = Math.max(maxArray(node_py));

    legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
        .data(recordTypes)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'legend')
        .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
            var rect_height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
            var offset = rect_height * (recordTypes.length-1);
            var horz = nodeLayoutRight + 15; /*  - 2*legendRectSize; */
            var vert = nodeLayoutBottom + (i * rect_height) - offset;
            return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
        });

    legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)
    .style('fill', function (d) {
        return d.color
    })
    .style('stroke', function (d) {
        return d.color
    });

    legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing + 3)
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.text;
    })
    .style('fill', '#757575');

}

var line_width_factor = 10.0 // width for the widest line

function call_width(d) {
    return (d.inc_calls + d.out_calls) / max_interactions * line_width_factor;
}

function text_width(d) {
    return (d.inc_texts + d.out_texts) / max_interactions * line_width_factor;
}

function total_width(d) {
    return (d.inc_calls + d.out_calls + d.inc_texts + d.out_texts) / max_interactions * line_width_factor + line_diff;
}

function line_perpendicular_shift(d, direction) {
    theta = getAngle(d);
    theta_perpendicular = theta + (Math.PI / 2) * direction;

    lineWidthOfOppositeLine = direction == 1 ? text_width(d) : call_width(d);
    shift = lineWidthOfOppositeLine / 2;

    delta_x = (shift + line_diff) * Math.cos(theta_perpendicular)
    delta_y = (shift + line_diff) * Math.sin(theta_perpendicular)

    return [delta_x, delta_y]

}

function line_radius_shift_to_edge(d, which_node) { // which_node = 0 if source, = 1 if target

    theta = getAngle(d);
    theta = (which_node == 0) ? theta : theta + Math.PI; // reverse angle if target node
    radius = (which_node == 0) ? node_radius(d.source) : node_radius(d.target) // d.source and d.target refer directly to the nodes (not indices)
    radius -= 2; // add stroke width

    delta_x = radius * Math.cos(theta)
        delta_y = radius * Math.sin(theta)

        return [delta_x, delta_y]

}

function getAngle(d) {
    rel_x = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    rel_y = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    return theta = Math.atan2(rel_y, rel_x);
}
```

**Links.csv**

```
source,target,inc_calls,out_calls,inc_texts,out_texts
0,1,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
0,2,0.0,0.0,1.0,3.0
0,3,3.0,9.0,5.0,7.0
0,4,2.0,12.0,9.0,14.0
0,5,5.0,9.0,9.0,13.0
0,6,5.0,17.0,2.0,25.0
0,7,6.0,13.0,7.0,16.0
0,8,7.0,7.0,8.0,8.0
0,9,3.0,10.0,8.0,20.0
0,10,5.0,10.0,6.0,23.0
0,11,8.0,10.0,13.0,15.0
0,12,9.0,18.0,9.0,22.0
0,13,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0
0,14,11.0,13.0,7.0,15.0
0,15,5.0,18.0,9.0,22.0
0,16,8.0,15.0,13.0,20.0
0,17,4.0,10.0,9.0,26.0
0,18,9.0,18.0,8.0,33.0
0,19,12.0,11.0,4.0,15.0
0,20,4.0,15.0,9.0,25.0
0,21,4.0,17.0,10.0,19.0
0,22,4.0,16.0,12.0,29.0
0,23,6.0,9.0,12.0,20.0
0,24,2.0,2.0,1.0,3.0
0,25,3.0,8.0,10.0,16.0
0,26,3.0,10.0,11.0,22.0
0,27,6.0,14.0,9.0,11.0
0,28,2.0,7.0,8.0,15.0
0,29,2.0,11.0,8.0,15.0
0,30,1.0,8.0,9.0,6.0
0,31,3.0,6.0,7.0,7.0
0,32,4.0,9.0,3.0,12.0
0,33,4.0,4.0,7.0,12.0
0,34,4.0,4.0,5.0,9.0
0,35,2.0,3.0,0.0,7.0
0,36,3.0,7.0,5.0,9.0
0,37,1.0,7.0,5.0,3.0
0,38,1.0,13.0,1.0,2.0
0,39,2.0,7.0,3.0,4.0
0,40,1.0,3.0,2.0,6.0
0,41,0.0,1.0,2.0,1.0
0,42,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0
0,43,0.0,3.0,1.0,5.0
0,44,0.0,1.0,0.0,2.0
0,45,4.0,1.0,1.0,10.0
0,46,2.0,7.0,3.0,5.0
0,47,5.0,7.0,3.0,5.0
0,48,2.0,5.0,4.0,10.0
0,49,3.0,3.0,5.0,13.0
1,15,10.0,30.0,13.0,37.0
2,8,16.0,9.0,24.0,15.0
2,43,4.0,10.0,9.0,16.0
5,48,3.0,5.0,0.0,4.0
6,37,11.0,25.0,15.0,34.0
8,48,12.0,4.0,7.0,2.0
9,42,25.0,9.0,29.0,15.0
9,45,11.0,3.0,16.0,5.0
12,24,4.0,15.0,13.0,16.0
14,31,18.0,9.0,29.0,12.0
14,33,5.0,10.0,4.0,9.0
15,28,8.0,5.0,16.0,5.0
16,36,14.0,11.0,10.0,19.0
23,38,3.0,11.0,6.0,10.0
26,42,9.0,23.0,17.0,21.0
27,46,12.0,12.0,15.0,21.0
29,39,8.0,15.0,9.0,20.0
29,47,8.0,27.0,19.0,24.0
33,46,6.0,4.0,13.0,13.0
37,43,10.0,12.0,6.0,21.0
```

**Nodes.csv**

```
no_network_info
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Does the firefox console say anything? It could also be easier if you included your data files.

Comment: Ok, I've done that now. Didn't know about the Firefox console - I've added the output from that now.

Comment: Are you using a local version of d3? It might be out of date. Try using <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

Comment: I am using a local version of d3, but it is very recent. Changing to the remote version sadly didn't fix it.

Comment: Based on Katherine's debugging that identified the `current_gradient` variable as the source of the problem, I looked for that particular variable in your code: It looks like you're using `String.substring` to extract an `id` value from a `url(#id)` style property.  It might be as simple as that Firefox is returning `url("#id")` or some other format that isn't parsing correctly.

Comment: As for a solution: try using presentation attributes (D3's `.attr()` function) instead of styles; that way, the browsers won't try to standardize the string you set, like they do with styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is with this line:

```
defs.select(current_gradient).remove();
```

But above that is the real problem. Replace:

```
current_gradient = current_gradient.substring(4, current_gradient.length - 1);
```

With:

```
if (current_gradient.match("http")) {
    var parts = current_gradient.split("/");
    current_gradient = parts[-1];
} else {
    current_gradient = current_gradient.substring(4, current_gradient.length - 1);
}
```

When you originally set the current_gradient in Chrome, it is set to "url(somevalue)" whereas in Firefox is it set to "url(fullpath/somevalue)". So you need to remove all the path info, not just the "url()" bit. Splitting the slash and taking the last value from the split is probably the easiest way to do that.

Comment: The value of current_gradient in Chrome is something like: #line-gradient98575, while in Firefox it's something like: ""http://localhost:9013/#line-gradient43891") transparen" which is why there is a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Now it runs as the `SyntaxError` has been removed, but it is sadly too slow to be useful. This is likely due to the `mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create d3.js:553:4` line in the console. I was unsure whether to edit this question or post a new one. I ended up doing the latter. If interested, go look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705499/mutating-the-prototype-causes-slow-performance-in-firefox-for-d3-force-layou